# Nodejs how to block the actual endpoint that was requested from an .all endpoint?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've got an `.all` endpoint which gets called for all endpoints connected to `accounts`. What I want to do in it is check a token and then if it's true, progress to the endpoint that was actually requested.

I thought `next()` was supposed to do this but the other requests are being called regardless of the token being valid or not.

What am I doing wrong?

```
router.all(['/accounts', '/accounts/*'], (req, res, next) => {

  admin.auth().verifyIdToken(req.headers.authorization)
  .then((token) => {

    // TODO: Fix so that this actually works, now the other routes are being called regardless
    next();
  }).catch((error) => {

    res.send({
      error: error,
      data: {
        account: null,
        message: 'Invalid token',
        status: 401
      }
    });
  });
});

router.post('/accounts', (req.res, next) => {});
router.post('/accounts/:uid', (req.res, next) => {});
```

How can I make sure that the .all endpoint only continues to either /accounts or /accounts/:uid if the verifyToken function is successful? Apparently next() doesn't do anything in terms of blocking consecutive requests.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't `return` in the catch then it will continue to the next route, if you return it breaks the chain:

```
router.all(['/accounts', '/accounts/*'], (req, res, next) => {

  admin.auth().verifyIdToken(req.headers.authorization)
  .then((token) => {
    next();
  }).catch((error) => {

    return res.send({
      error: error,
      data: {
        account: null,
        message: 'Invalid token',
        status: 401
      }
    });
  });
});
```